# Robocopy from previous versions of the folder windows 2008 server

Tags: windows, robocopy

I have moved around 160 Gigabytes from fileshare server to usb drive and deleted the files from the server and i realised something went wrong , files were not in the usb driver.
in the server i can find the previous version of the deleted folder , its location is  \localhost\G$@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Files\Leavers 2  ,,,

I tried to do robocopy from there to usb driver again but i get the error below.

Any ideas of how can i robocopy them please?

```
C:\Users\Hazal.Altin>robocopy "\\localhost\G$\@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Fi
les\Leavers 2" "F:\"  /MIR /COPY:DATSOU /ZB /R:1 /W:10 /TEE

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tue Dec 18 08:38:52 2018

   Source : \\localhost\G$\@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Files\Leavers 2\
     Dest : F:\"  \MIR \COPY:DATSOU \ZB \R:1 \W:10 \TEE\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2018/12/18 08:38:52 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Accessing Destination Directory F:\"
 \MIR \COPY:DATSOU \ZB \R:1 \W:10 \TEE\
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: Please, post the error message as a text to the post and not as an image.

Comment: l robocopy "\\localhost\G$\@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Fi
les\Leavers 2" "F:\"  /MIR /COPY:DATSOU /ZB /R:1 /W:10 /TEE

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tue Dec 18 08:38:52 2018

   Source : \\localhost\G$\@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Files\Leavers 2\
     Dest : F:\"  \MIR \COPY:DATSOU \ZB \R:1 \W:10 \TEE\

    Files : *.*

  Options : *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

Comment: Can you add the files you want to copy? `"*"` should do fine if you want to copy all of them. I have the impression that `robocopy` does not understand what you're trying to do, based on its interpretation of the destination directory.

Comment: @Dominique where shall i add "*" ?  when i copied before i didnt need to specify any kind of files it found itself. i think location of the shadow copy is making some problem

Comment: robocopy "\\localhost\G$\@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Fi
les\Leavers 2" "F:\" "*" /...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So Guys ,

Thank you to everyone i found a way by myself with this one , please see down below if anyone looking .

Restore files from Shadow Copy

Right click on the folder your trying to restore from shadow copy and chose ‘Previous versions’. Chose a date and click on open.

Right click on any file or folder within the previous folder and chose ‘properties’. Under ‘General’ copy what reads in ‘location’ – .e.g.:

\localhost\G$@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Files

Open cmd.exe and type in:
subst X: "\localhost\G$@GMT-2018.12.14-12.00.13\Old PC Files"

Open powershell and use robocopy to copy content of X: e.g.:

robocopy X: D:\Folder\  /MIR /COPY:DATSOU /ZB /R:1 /W:10 /TEE /log:

Check that all files have been copied.

When finished, in cmd, type

subst X: /D